# how to get the database values in to array list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i had an array list statically like

```
    List l=new ArrayList();
      l.add("1");
      l.add("2");
      l.add("3");
      l.add("4");
      l.add("5");
```

but i want  to get the database column values in to my array list dynamically how this can be achieved please suggest me this im using oracle xe

Comment: Have you succeeded to get data out of database?

Comment: While it is not related to your particular question, I would strongly urge you to use generics: `List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();`.  There is no reason to avoid the extra type-safety and clarity it gives you.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to connect to databases in Java is JDBC, and Sun publishes a [JDBC basics lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/).

In your case, the very rough solution would be something like the following:

```
List l=new ArrayList();

// TODO handle exceptions
Connection conn = ...; // create the connection according to your DB details
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select Column from YourTable");
while (rs.next()) {
    l.add(rs.getString(1));
}
// TODO close these in a finally block
rs.close();
stmt.close();
```